# How to merge two objects (associative array) with same key into one object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two objects:

```
var arr= [
  0: { selectedAns: "test answer 1", id: "28", status: "answered" }
]
```

and:

```
var answerList = [
  0: { selectedAns: "test answer 2 ques 5", id: "27", status: "answered" },
  1: { selectedAns: "test answer 3 ques 6", id: "29", status: "answered"}
]
```

When I do this:

```
arr1.push(arr);
arr1.push(answerList);
```

I am getting this result:

```
var arr1=[0:{
    0:{selectedAns: "test answer 2 ques 5", id: "27", status: "answered"}
}
1:{
    0:{selectedAns: "test answer 1", id: "28", status: "answered"}
    1:{selectedAns: "test answer 3 ques 6", id: "29", status: "answered"}
}]
```

But I want something like this:

```
    var arr1=[
    0:{selectedAns: "test answer 2 ques 5", id: "27", status: "answered"}

    1:{selectedAns: "test answer 1", id: "28", status: "answered"}

    2:{selectedAns: "test answer 3 ques 6", id: "29", status: "answered"}
]
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Note: I am removing duplicates from objects before merging two objects, even if any key has duplicate value like here in status key. Still, I need to merge both the objects. Per my requirement only the id key needs to be unique, so I need a way to merge the two objects as above.

Comment: Get rid of all the `0:` , `1:` etc syntax shown...none of that is valid syntax. An array of objects looks like `[{},{},{}]`

Comment: Looks like you have two arrays, `arr` and `answerList`. Then you try to address something called `arr1`. What is it?

Comment: arr1 is a variable in which i am trying to store the result after merging both arr and answerList .@Roamer-1888

Comment: why the array(s). Why not simply deal with native js objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), which need an assignment of the new array.

```js
var arr = [{ selectedAns: "test answer 1", id: "28", status: "answered" }],
    answerList = [{ selectedAns: "test answer 2 ques 5", id: "27", status: "answered" }, { selectedAns: "test answer 3 ques 6", id: "29", status: "answered" }];
    
arr = arr.concat(answerList);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or use [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) with [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for taking an array as parameter.

```js
var arr = [{ selectedAns: "test answer 1", id: "28", status: "answered" }],
    answerList = [{ selectedAns: "test answer 2 ques 5", id: "27", status: "answered" }, { selectedAns: "test answer 3 ques 6", id: "29", status: "answered" }];
    
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, answerList);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With ES6 you could push the values with [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) which takes an array as parameters.

```js
var arr = [{ selectedAns: "test answer 1", id: "28", status: "answered" }],
    answerList = [{ selectedAns: "test answer 2 ques 5", id: "27", status: "answered" }, { selectedAns: "test answer 3 ques 6", id: "29", status: "answered" }];
    
arr.push(...answerList);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @M0ns1f, the indices are not valid parts of an array in javascript. i assume this is only a part of displaying arrays in the console.

Comment: Well if he want to use the indices, see my answer and give me your opinion ^^'

Comment: @NinaScholz thanks for responding so quick... you saved my life, arr = arr.concat(answerList); did the work for me thank again...

Answer (score 0):

Well using javascript you can push the `answerList` array to the `arr1` using for loop see this function :

```js
var arr1 = [];
var arr={0:{selectedAns: "test answer 1", id: "28", status: "answered"}};

var answerList={0:{selectedAns: "test answer 2 ques 5", id: "27", status: "answered"},1:{selectedAns: "test answer 3 ques 6", id: "29", status: "answered"}};

arr1.push(arr);//push first array
pashingarray(answerList);

//function to push an array
function pashingarray(arrtobepush)
{
var lenghtar = 0;
for(var key in arrtobepush) {
    if(arrtobepush.hasOwnProperty(key)){
       lenghtar++;//get the lenght of the array
    }
}
for(var i = 0;i<lenghtar;i++)//loop the array to push the content
{
  var keytopush = i+1;
  var arraytopush = {[keytopush]:arrtobepush[i]};
  arr1.push(arraytopush);
}
}

console.log(arr1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```